# Backbone.js : a Simple render function

Tags: backbone.js

I'm learning Backbone.js, I can't find what is wrong with this code:

```
NView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'span',
    render: function(){
        $(this.el).html('<h3>' + this.model.get('comments') + this.model.get('minutes') + '</h3>');
    }
});

newView = new NView({   model: NModelo });

newView.render();

console.log(newView.el);
```

I think it is supposed to log this:

```
<span> <h3> .... </h3> </span>
```

But it only logs a `<span> </span>`, without anything between the tags, why?

Comment: Seems to work fine (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/nds1qco3/). What is `NModelo`? The name suggests `NModelo = Backbone.Model.extend(...)` rather than the `NModelo = new SomeModel` that the view would expect.

Comment: This is kind of weird. NModelo is = `Backbone.Model.extend()`, sorry for not following naming conventions. It seems that @jgillich answer is correct, although I don't fully understand why.

Comment: Are you just missing the little `▶` glyph in the console? Some browsers want you to manually open up the DOM node to see what's inside.

Comment: Just a quick tip. You can substitute "$(this.el)" with "this.$el". Backbone creates it automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `el` property is a DOM element, not a string. To get the full HTML string, you can use use the `outerHTML` property:

```
console.log(newView.el.outerHTML);
```

Comment: Hi, this works, thanks. However, could you please elaborate? when I do `console.log($(anyjqueryelement).html())`, it works correctly.

Comment: @alejoss `$.fn.html` returns the `innerHTML` property, which is like `outerHTML` but without the element itself. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element